# Deleted Linux Mint Partitions - Can't Boot Windows Anymore

Tags: dual-boot

Can't Boot Windows anymore.. I tried installing ubuntu alongside windows to solve the problem, but after Making partitions manually during install (which I triple checked I did correct) I get a warning saying that there is no EFI partition and to proceed with caution as it cause my to have a u bootable pc???

Comment: Probably easy question.. But can I make a bootable usb using a live Ubuntu USB that I already have, or even using a USB I have with kali? Only Kali is only one with persistence..

Comment: that's not true ubuntu live USB can be created to be persistent as with most linuxes. it's only a default for Kali for ubuntu the option used to be visible. are you trying to have windosw only or windows and linux dual boot?

Comment: Well I want Ubuntu alongside my windows. I initially had windows and mint but I wanted to switch to Ubuntu and instead of properly removing mint, I just deleted the Linux mint partitions leaving my two WI dows partitions with a large unallocated space. But now windows won't boot and need it direly for court aha "you live and you learn right aha"

Comment: oh ok let me make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is boot to a ubuntu live USB (either use the one you used to install or if you reformatted it since then, make a new one)

and then install ubuntu.

that's it.

it'll detect windows durring the installation (say install allongside windows) and after it's done you'll be able to boot both.

(next time you want to switch os do this dirrectly, don't ever delete system partitions from a running system, you can partition from the installer usb)

hope this helped! :)

Comment: I will give it a shot. If this works I'm literally gonna be one very VERY happy man! Regardless.. Thank you for taking the time to help me! I will try it now and let you know :) cheers

Comment: Where is the command you just gave me to enter? It dissapeared

Comment: I tried installing ubuntu from the live USB (thankfully I created before I deleted the Linux mint partitions) which during the install I created my partitions;

Comment: Sorry, didn't send my full responce. My appolagies, here you go lol. I tried installing ubuntu from the live USB (thankfully I created before I deleted the Linux mint partitions) which during the install I created my partitions;  15000MB ROOT / 12000MB SWAP / 120400 MB HOME. However I this is what happens..    (two pics in link) if that's allowed    https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=13cmNqzza4bqxx5WVIdnQn5pUkVVxDwtl

Comment: https://flic.kr/p/2gdUJPa        https://flic.kr/p/2gdUuaU

Comment: I honestly feel I'm not justified in even giving an answer because I literally am just fallowing what I was shown to do months ago when I first started taking Linux on as a hobby.. So as to wether i can live with or without it doesn't matter.  I have 8gb ram I'm sure it'll be ok without.. Do I proceed even tho I got that warning about there not being an EFI Partition?

Comment: oh no. if it says you need efi. then your windows is in efi and ubuntu must be too (efi is the new way) so make a 500 mb efi partition and it'll be happy. but yeah you don't need swap. It's stopped being usefull a while ago.

Comment: Do I make them all primary?

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.. She works!

Comment: I knew she would! ;) you're welcome! :)

Comment: I seem to be having a seperated issue.. I'll post the question, if I need to repost a whole new question I can just let me know so I can be sure to abid by the rules.. When booting I hit F9 which brings me to the screen where I can choose what to boot from (wether that be USB, Internal Notebook HD, CDROM, etc.. Well after I made me two partitions (500MB efi & Remaining MB / ) the warning disappeared and all was well. After installation completed I restarted my laptop and hit F9 so I can select my Notebook hard drive as I like to keep. USB as first, and well it's not working..

Comment: yeah that's a seperate issue, I don't even think it qualifies for askubuntu. sounds like a hardware-only issue. but if you don't want the usb in your bios boot list simply grab the usb with your hand and remove it from it's usb port. simple as that.

Comment: http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii614/braddesjardins3321/Mobile%20Uploads/20190614_052849_zpsyz2bmup7.jpg.                                             http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii614/braddesjardins3321/Mobile%20Uploads/20190614_052904_HDR_zps2n0ks8e8.jpg.                                        http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii614/braddesjardins3321/Mobile%20Uploads/20190614_052927_zpsrg7kqpmd.jpg.                                                http://i1262.photobucket.com/albums/ii614/braddesjardins3321/Mobile%20Uploads/20190614_053000_HDR_zpsexdjhqvk.jpg